# Polymer 1.x: Observers

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

Ultimately, I want to select individual states [from this geochart](http://jsbin.com/wuqugigeha/1/edit?html,console,output). But this question is limited to getting the observer labeled `_computeData` to fire in response to mutating the array of `selected` states.

Reproduce the problem with the following steps:

1. [Open this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wuqugigeha/1/edit?html,console,output).
2. Clear the console.
3. Select the state of Texas.

Note the console reads:

> You selected: Colorado,South Dakota,Texas

which is expected per this line:

```
console.log('You selected: ' + this.selected); // Logs properly
```

However, I expect the console to ***also*** read:

> selected

per this line:

```
_computeData: function() {
  console.log('selected'); // Does not log properly; function not called?
  ...
```

which should be called by the following set of observers.

http://jsbin.com/wuqugigeha/1/edit?html,console,output

```
...
observers: [
  '_computeData(items.*, selected.*)',
  '_dataChanged(data.*)',
],
...
```

## Question

**What's going on here? Why isn't the observer calling the `_computeData` method? What can be done to get the method to fire after mutating the `selected` array?**

http://jsbin.com/wuqugigeha/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="google-chart/google-chart.html" rel="import"> </head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="x-element"> <template>
      <style>
        google-chart {
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <button on-tap="_show">Show Values</button>
    <button on-tap="clearAll">Clear All</button>
    <button on-tap="selectAll">Select All</button>
      <div>[[selected]]</div>
      <google-chart
        id="geochart"
        type="geo"
        options="[[options]]"
        data="[[data]]"
        xon-google-chart-select="_onGoogleChartSelect">
      </google-chart>
    </template>
    <script>
      (function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-element',
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming', ].sort();
              },
            },
            color: {
              type: String, // '#455A64'
              value: function() {
                return 'blue';
              }
            },
            options: {
              type: Object,
              notify: true,
              reflectToAttribute: true,
              computed: '_computeOptions(color)',
            },
            selected: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true,
              reflectToAttribute: true,
              value: function() {
                return [];
              },
              //observer: '_computeData', // Unsuccessfully tried this
            },
            data: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true,
              reflectToAttribute: true,
              //computed: '_computeData(items.*, selected.*)', // Unsuccessfully tried this
            },
          },
          observers: [
            '_computeData(items.*, selected.*)',
            '_dataChanged(data.*)',
          ],
          // Bind select event listener to chart
          ready: function() {
            var _this = this;
            this.$.geochart.addEventListener('google-chart-select', function(e) {
              this._onGoogleChartSelect(e);
            }.bind(_this));
          },
          _computeOptions: function() {
            return {
              region: 'US',
              displayMode: 'regions',
              resolution: 'provinces',
              legend: 'none',
              defaultColor: 'white',
              colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#E0E0E0', this.color],
                minValue: 0,  
                maxValue: 1,
              }
            }
          },    
          // On select event, compute 'selected'
          _onGoogleChartSelect: function(e) {
            var string = e.path[0].textContent.split('Select')[0].trim(), // e.g. 'Ohio'
                selected = this.selected, // Array of selected items
                index = selected.indexOf(string);
            // If 'string' is not in 'selected' array, add it; else delete it
            if (index === -1) {
              selected.push(string);
              selected.sort();
            } else {
              selected.splice(index, 1);
            }
            this.set('selected', selected);
            console.log('You selected: ' + this.selected); // Logs properly
            // Next step should be '_computeData' per observers
          },
          // After 'items' populates or 'selected' changes, compute 'data'
          _computeData: function() {
            console.log('selected'); // Does not log properly; function not called?
            var data = [],
                items = this.items,
                selected = this.selected,
                i = items.length;
            while (i--) {
              data.unshift([items[i], selected.indexOf(items[i]) > -1 ? 1 : 0]);
            }
            data.unshift(['State', 'Select']);
            this.set('data', data);
          },
          // After 'data' changes, redraw chart
          // Add delay to avoid 'google not defined' error
          _dataChanged: function() {
            var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
              _this._drawChart();
            }.bind(_this), 100)
          },
          // After delay, draw chart
          _drawChart: function() {
            var data = this.data,
                dataTable = this.$.geochart._createDataTable(data);
            console.log(dataTable);
            this.$.geochart._chartObject.draw(dataTable, this.options);
          },
          clearAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', []);
          },
          selectAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', this.items);
          },
          _show: function() {
            console.log('items: ' + this.items);
            console.log('selected: ' + this.selected);
            console.log('data: ' + this.data);
          },
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <x-element color="red" selected='["Colorado", "South Dakota"]'></x-element>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (index === -1) {
    selected.push(string);
    selected.sort();
} else {
    selected.splice(index, 1);
}
this.set('selected', selected);
```

Polymer's data-handling methods like `set` allow you to give Polymer specific information about how your data is changing, allowing Polymer to make very fast DOM updates.

In this case, you are doing work where Polymer cannot see it (i.e. the array manipulations), and then asking `set` to figure out what happened. However, when you call `this.set('selected', selected);`, Polymer sees that the identity of `selected` hasn't changed (that is, it's the same Array object as before) and it simply stops processing. (Fwiw, this is a common problem, so we are considering a modification that will go ahead and examine the array anyway.)

The solution is two-fold:

1) In the case where you are sorting the array, create a fresh array reference to for `set` via `slice()` :

```
if (index === -1) {
    selected.push(string);
    selected.sort();
    this.set('selected', selected.slice());
```

2) In the case where you are simply splicing, use the [`splice`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation) helper function :

```
} else {
    this.splice('selected', index, 1);
}
```

Ideally you avoid sorting your array, then you can use `this.push` directly.

**Note**: with these changes `_computeData` is being called, but now it's being called way too many times. Partly this is due to observing `selected.*` which will fire for `selected`, `selected.length`, and `selected.splices`. Observing `selected.length` instead of `selected.*` might help.

### UPDATE

There were three other major problems with your example:

1. `data` is bound to to the `google-chart` (i.e. `data="[[data]]"`) so the chart will redraw itself when `data` changes and we can remove `_drawChart` completely.
2. `_computeData(items.*, selected.*)` is too aggressive, as `selected.*` will fire for changes in 'selected.length', 'selected.splices', and `selected`. Instead use `_computeData(items, selected.length)`.
3. `google-chart` itself appears to be buggy. In particular, it's own `drawChart` is not set up to be properly re-entrant. The most obvious problem is that every time the chart draws, it adds an additional selection listener (which causes multiplying `chart-select` events to fire on your application). I would **appreciate** it if you would [file a bug](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/issues) on `google-chart` and link back to this SO. :)

Here is a modified version where I've monkey patched `google-chart.drawChart`, fixed the other two major problems, and made a variety of smaller repairs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="google-chart/google-chart.html" rel="import"> </head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="x-element"> <template>
      <style>
        google-chart {
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <button on-tap="_show">Show Values</button>
    <button on-tap="clearAll">Clear All</button>
    <button on-tap="selectAll">Select All</button>
      <div>[[selected]]</div>
      <google-chart
        id="geochart"
        type="geo"
        options="[[options]]"
        data="[[data]]"
  on-google-chart-select="_onGoogleChartSelect">
      </google-chart>
    </template>
    <script>
      (function() {
        
        // monkey-patching google-chart
        var gcp = Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement('google-chart'));
        gcp.drawChart = function() {
          if (this._canDraw) {
            if (!this.options) {
              this.options = {};
            }
            if (!this._chartObject) {
              var chartClass = this._chartTypes[this.type];
              if (chartClass) {
                this._chartObject = new chartClass(this.$.chartdiv);
                google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(this._chartObject,
                    'ready', function() {
                        this.fire('google-chart-render');
                    }.bind(this));

                google.visualization.events.addListener(this._chartObject,
                    'select', function() {
                        this.selection = this._chartObject.getSelection();
                        this.fire('google-chart-select', { selection: this.selection });
                    }.bind(this));
                if (this._chartObject.setSelection){
                  this._chartObject.setSelection(this.selection);
                }
              }
            }
            if (this._chartObject) {
              this._chartObject.draw(this._dataTable, this.options);
            } else {
              this.$.chartdiv.innerHTML = 'Undefined chart type';
            }
          }
        };
        
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-element',
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming', ].sort();
              },
            },
            color: {
              type: String, // '#455A64'
              value: 'blue'
            },
            options: {
              type: Object,
              computed: '_computeOptions(color)',
            },
            selected: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [];
              }
            },
            data: {
              type: Array,
              computed: '_computeData(items, selected.length)'
            },
          },
          _computeOptions: function() {
            return {
              region: 'US',
              displayMode: 'regions',
              resolution: 'provinces',
              legend: 'none',
              defaultColor: 'white',
              colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#E0E0E0', this.color],
                minValue: 0,  
                maxValue: 1,
              }
            }
          }, 
    // On select event, compute 'selected'
          _onGoogleChartSelect: function(e) {
            console.log('_onGoogleChartSelect: ', e.detail)
            var string = e.path[0].textContent.split('Select')[0].trim(), // e.g. 'Ohio'
                selected = this.selected, // Array of selected items
                index = selected.indexOf(string);
            // If 'string' is not in 'selected' array, add it; else delete it
            if (index === -1) {
              this.push('selected', string);
            } else {
              this.splice('selected', index, 1);
            }
            // Next step should be '_computeData' per observers
            console.log('_select:', this.selected);
          },
          // After 'items' populates or 'selected' changes, compute 'data'
          _computeData: function(items, selectedInfo) {
            console.log('_computeData');
            var data = [],
                selected = this.selected,
                i = items.length;
            while (i--) {
              data.unshift([items[i], selected.indexOf(items[i]) > -1 ? 1 : 0]);
            }
            data.unshift(['State', 'Select']);
            return data;
          },
          clearAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', []);
          },
          selectAll: function() {
            this.set('selected', this.items);
          },
          _show: function() {
            console.log('items: ' + this.items);
            console.log('selected: ' + this.selected);
            console.log('data: ' + this.data);
          },
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <x-element color="red" selected='["Colorado", "South Dakota"]'></x-element>
</body>

</html>
```

HTH

---

Random extra stuff:

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    _this._drawChart();
}.bind(_this), 100)
```

You need to **either** capture the value of `this` (`_this`) **or** use `bind`, but it doesn't make sense to do both.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this._drawChart();
}.bind(this), 100)
```

... is enough.

Comment: It won't work for the same reason `set('selected', selected)` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much. +1. Bug report filed here... https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/issues/81

Comment: Thank you for making the report, that really helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example of implementation of the accepted solution](http://jsbin.com/xonanucela/edit?html,console,output).

http://jsbin.com/xonanucela/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<x-element></x-element>

<dom-module id="x-element">
<template>

  <br><br>
  <paper-button on-tap="_addNew">Click To Add</paper-button>
  <p>
    <strong>Items</strong>:
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
      <span>[[item]] </span>
    </template>
  </p>

</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-element',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          return ['foo'];
        }
      }
    },
    _addNew: function() {
      var a = this.items; // Clones array
      a.push('bar'); // Updates "value"
      console.log('a', a);
      this.set('items', a.slice()); // Updates "identity"
      console.log('items', this.items);
    },

  });
</script>
</dom-module>
</body>
```